# datalist editing is not working?

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I am working on data list item editing concept,i think i am done all code correct but when click on edit button blank page is showing please see this problem and send any bugs and salvation suggestion please

HTML CODE

```
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="outlet_id" OnEditCommand="DataList1_EditCommand" OnCancelCommand="DataList1_CancelCommand" RepeatColumns="2"> 
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("outlet_id") %>' ></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("company_name") %>' ></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="edit"  />
            <asp:Button ID="delete" runat="server" Text="Del" CommandName="del" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
        id<asp:TextBox ID="id" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("outlet_id") %>'></asp:TextBox> 
        name<asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("company_name") %>'  ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CommandName="update" Text="update" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" CommandName="cancel" Text="Cancel" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>


    </form>
</body>
```

and c# code here bellow

page load

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        bind();
    }

}
```

Edit command code

```
protected void DataList1_EditCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DataList1.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
        DataList1.DataBind();

    }
```

cancel command code

```
protected void DataList1_CancelCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    DataList1.EditItemIndex = -1;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
```

this is datalist binding

```
protected void bind()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strconnection);
    con.Open();
    string qry = "select top 10 outlet_id,company_name from outlet_table ";
    SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    Da.Fill(ds, "outlet");
    DataList1.DataSource = ds;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
```

this is a Client side html data showing after click on edit button

```
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Demo.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="zVlNF4jkNpf9ZmIBtYaHSdSPa9l8zKVA4H0JXxnhqVytzfrbVWUuOuY8004hXYRY8KuBKqPKgV3kS4RQBegrJQ5LErL3VdV9TeluNoxAZLtDu0/62xR8Ij/jD638pPKb">
</div>

<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" id="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" value="">
</div>





    </form>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebind the data to your Datalist.

This:

```
protected void DataList1_EditCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DataList1.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
        DataList1.DataBind();

    }
```

Should look like this:

```
protected void DataList1_EditCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DataList1.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
        bind();

    }
```

On post back the Datalist loses its datasource and needs it again.

Comment: You call an undefined method.